# Generate Random Forest feature importance plots from 3D arrays

Tags: python-3.x, random-forest, feature-selection

After carrying our a `librosa` MFCC feature extraction on 1000 audio files, I end up with an `X_test` array of size 1000 x 40 x 174 (40 features as I set n_mfcc=40).  In order for me to pass this through the `random forest` classifier, I scaled and then flattened the array.  My new `X_test` now has a size of 1000 x 6960.  How do I go about correctly generating the feature importance histogram?

This is the code that I used for the `feature importance` plot but not sure if this is the correct approach:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

x_train # this has a shape of 1000 x 40 x 174
X_train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(x_train.reshape(-1, x_train.shape[-1])).reshape(x_train.shape)

X_train = np.array([features_2d.flatten() for features_2d in X_train_scaled])


X = pd.DataFrame(X_train)  # X_train here is already flattened to 1000 x 6960

feature_names = [f"feature {i}" for i in range(X.shape[1])]
clf = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=0)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)


importances = clf.feature_importances_
std = np.std([tree.feature_importances_ for tree in clf.estimators_], axis=0)

forest_importances = pd.Series(importances, index=feature_names)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.figure(figsize=(13, 10))
forest_importances.plot.bar(yerr=std, ax=ax)
ax.set_title("Feature importances using MDI")
ax.set_ylabel("Mean decrease in impurity")
fig.tight_layout()
```

With this code, I get this plot:

[image]

Can you tell me if this is the correct approach?  If this approach is correct, how can I generate a more "readable" plot for the Feature Importance?  Thanks!

Comment: I suspect that if you open this plot in the matplotlib GUI window and zoom in, the x-axis labels (which are currently overlapping each other for lack of space) will start appearing. So that part would be purely a visual issue.

Comment: @DominikStańczak, the approach to flatten the 3D array is correct then?  If so, how to go about plotting just the first 15 important  features?

Comment: Hard to tell, as you didn't show the flattening part! You can use `sort_values` on your pandas `Series` together with `.tail(n=15)` to get the most important ones.

Comment: @DominikStańczak, I have added the portion of the code for the flattening.

Comment: Your first operation `x_train.reshape(-1, x_train.shape[-1])` turns that into a (40000, 174) array, which is worrisome. It seems you can just do the whole thing at once with `y = scaler.fit_transform(x.reshape(-1, x.shape[1] * x.shape[2]))`. First reshape without messing with the first dimension, then scale everything - unless there's something I don't understand about the `StandardScaler`.

Comment: Can you give me a quick explanation of your code `X_train = scaler.fit_transform(x_train.reshape(-1, x_train.shape[1] * x_train.shape[2]))`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246311/discussion-between-joe-and-dominik-stanczak).